# What's the difference between code construction and architecture?

Tags: terminology

When I read the book Code Complete, the word "construction" is referenced frequently.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that **architecture is the design** whereas **construction is the implementation**.

Answer (score 2):

An analogy with a book could be:

- Architecture is the plot
- Construction is the text

Answer (score 1):

The software architecture of a program or computing system is the structure or structures of the system, which comprise software components, the externally visible properties of those components, and the relationships between them.

Construction is the implementation of the design

Answer (score 0):

Just like with houses, the construction (of the house) realizes the architecture (the plan).

Answer (score 0):

Using a house as an analagy architecture is creating the drawings explaining what rooms the house will have, how they will be laid out, etc. Construction is the guys that show up with hammars and wood, take a look at the architecture and start building the house.